# Dynamic Concatenation in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, concatenation

Let's say I have an array of data and a variable (or multiple variables)

```
var i = 1;
var arr = {
        1: ['whatever' + i,'there are ' + i + ' dogs in the yard.', etc], 
    }
```

Is there a way to dynamically update the variable(s) in the array later on in a function?

So

```
function start() {
i++;
alert(arr[1][0]);
}
```

Would output "whatever2" instead of "whatever1"

Comment: What do you mean with 'update the variable'?. Please, explain it better

Comment: Your question is not clear... if you think about changing `i` later on, that's not possible. `'whatever' + i` and `'there are ' + i + ' dogs in the yard.'` are evaluated when the array is defined, i.e. the value of `i` is determined *at that moment* and that value is concatenated with the other string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use functions instead:

```
var i = 1;
var arr = {
    1: [
        function() { return 'whatever' + i },
        function() { return 'there are ' + i + ' dogs in the yard.' },
        function() { return 'etc' }
    ], 
}:
```

Which would change your calls to:

```
function start() {
    i++;
    alert(arr[1][0]());
}
```

Comment: Clever. This is the closest to what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could have an array and `push()` stuff you need, but when the string is made, it won't change anymore.

```
var array = ['whatever',i,'there are ',i,' dogs in the yard.'];
array.push('more stuff');
array.push('even more stuff');
var string = array.join('')
//string = 'whatever[whatever "i" is during join]there are[whatever "i" is during join]dogs in the yard.more stuffeven more stuff'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var arr = function(i){
    return {
        1: ['whatever' + i,'there are ' + i + ' dogs in the yard.', etc],
    }
}
var anyNumber = 1;
var updatedVar = arr(anyNumber);
```